# iOS 5 - Multitasking Gesture on iPad Simulator

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios-simulator

is there anyone know how to try multitasking gesture, the new feature of iOS 5 on iPad Simulator..? I've run on iOS 5 Simulator but I don't know how to swipe with four finger on simulator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortuately, the iOS Simulator is not capable of accepting advanced gestures like the multitask gestures. As far as I know, without using some sort of third party input system the Simulator does not have a way to input more than two touch points.

Comment: well, i don't know with you, But, few hours ago, accidentally I could show multitasking feature (swipe up with four finger) on simulator. Now, I try to figure it out again and it can't....

:(

Comment: That's bizarre. Perhaps there is a command somewhere to perform the gesture? I've not played around with the iOS 5 simulator extensively myself, but I don't recall anything like that. I'll have to look into this a bit more.

Comment: Ah, I found the shortcut... ^_^

Just double click on home button... :)